# Pushing a directory in Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to push a directory in to heroku. The directory is within my local /.git/ folder.

I'm running the following command through git bash.
First I created this:

```
heroku create --stack=cedar abcservices
```

then

```
git push heroku master
```

but then I'm getting an error:

> Initializing repository, done
>   error src refspec master does not match any
>   error failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:rocky-crag-8723.git'

Answer (score 0):

The name of your application is `rocky-crag-8723` and not `abcservices`.Either login to heroku via broswer and rename your application or edit the `.git/config` file and replace `abcservices.git` with `rocky-crag-8723.git`

In the second case you will have to compromise your application name,and in the first case,your preferred application may not be available .